# Insert into the same table where the trigger (before insert) is executed

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, duplicates, database-trigger

I have to do a trigger that have to write the same column twice but with one different value, example:

The before insert statement is:

```
BEFORE INSERT ON MXGLCOMP_CLOUD
```

The data I received is: 12345, RAIL, 075, HDFG

But also, I want to insert into MXGLCOMP_CLOUD the same data but like this:
12345, RAIL, 069, HDFG.

I wrote the following code but I'm afraid that the trigger will fall into a infinite loop due the insert I do in the same trigger.

```
create or replace TRIGGER MXGLCOMP_CLOUD_TRG 
BEFORE INSERT ON MXGLCOMP_CLOUD 
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MXGLCOMP_CLOUD (ACTIVE, COMPTEXT, COMPVALUE, EXTERNALREFID)
    VALUES (:NEW.ACTIVE, :NEW.COMPTEXT, '069', :NEW.EXTERNALREFID);
END;
```

Is this ok? What I have to do? As I said before, I didn't run the test because I don't want that infinite loop.

Comment: Why do this in a trigger - why not do both inserts together from your application? If the 075 and 069 are fixed values then it's simple to avoid the infinite loop (well, not quite infinite, it'll fail eventually) by checking the value of the new row before deciding to create a new one, but this seems like a bad idea. Why even have both rows physically stored?

Comment: why not do both inserts together from your application?: This data is sended by other system, in fact they send it like GB_CORP, and I have to change this GB_CORP for 069 and 075.

Comment: Why even have both rows physically stored: Cause this value help to create 2 new structures where, if is 069 we need to add, for example 069.CHILE and if is 075 we need to add 075-PERU, and we need both of them.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already suspect, your current code will loop because the insert inside the trigger will cause the trigger to fire again, and that will do another insert, which will cause the trigger to fire, which will ... etc. But Oracle will terminate when it spots that happening, indirectly:

```
 ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded
 ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA.MXGLCOMP_CLOUD_TRG", line 7
```

Avoiding that is simple in this case: just check the value being inserted and only insert another new row if it's `'075'`:

```
create or replace trigger mxglcomp_cloud_trg 
before insert on mxglcomp_cloud 
for each row 
begin
  if :new.compvalue = '075' then
    insert into mxglcomp_cloud(active, comptext, compvalue, externalrefid)
    values(:new.active, :new.comptext, '069', :new.externalrefid);
  end if;
end;
/
```

Then a single insert into an empty table creates two rows:

```
insert into mxglcomp_cloud (active, comptext, compvalue, externalrefid)
values (12345, 'RAIL', '075', 'HDFG');

1 row inserted.

select * from mxglcomp_cloud;

    ACTIVE COMPTEXT   COM EXTERNALRE
---------- ---------- --- ----------
     12345 RAIL       069 HDFG      
     12345 RAIL       075 HDFG
```

However I still don't think this is a good idea, You are hiding business logic and data manipulation and there will be side-effects that users may not expect. Just as an obvious example, the insert reported "1 row inserted" when there were really two, which is confusing.

It would be better to perform two inserts from the application layer, or to put both in a procedure and make the application (and everyone else) call that.

---

If you actually want to change `'GB'` into two rows, one with `'075'` and one with `'069'`, then you can do the same thing but test for `'GB'` and change its value to `'075'`, while still inserting the extra row:

```
create or replace trigger mxglcomp_cloud_trg 
before insert on mxglcomp_cloud 
for each row 
begin
  if :new.compvalue = 'GB' then
    -- change this row from GB to 075
    :new.compvalue := '075';

    -- add another row for 069
    insert into mxglcomp_cloud(active, comptext, compvalue, externalrefid)
    values(:new.active, :new.comptext, '069', :new.externalrefid);
  end if;
end;
/
```

then (starting from an empty table again):

```
insert into mxglcomp_cloud (active, comptext, compvalue, externalrefid)
values (12345, 'RAIL', 'GB', 'HDFG');

1 row inserted.

select * from mxglcomp_cloud;

    ACTIVE COMPTEXT   COM EXTERNALRE
---------- ---------- --- ----------
     12345 RAIL       069 HDFG      
     12345 RAIL       075 HDFG
```

Comment: Ok, that look good. One more question, what if I get one row with the compvalue = GB and I need two rows, one with compvalue = 069 and other with compvalue = 075? How could I do that? (the value GB is not needed) I know that is not the best way to do, but I don't have control on the system that send the information but the client wanted like this.

Comment: Nothing happens, just that row is inserted. Your question doesn't mention GB. Only 075 causes an extra action. If you want different things to happen then add more conditons and what should happen when they are met. I've added an example for what I think you're describing.